# Error 522 - Server overloaded? How to troubleshoot?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, overloading, cloudflare

My site has been crashing recently displaying Error 522 (I use Cloudflare), and it looks like it is the result of a server overload (I have a VPS with GoDaddy). I tried to dig around and found the following lines in Apache's log:

```
Script timed out before returning headers: index.php, referer: http://www.777auction.ca/online/index.php?module=listings&controller=browse&action=index&show=all&limit=80&sort=ending_asc&listing_type=auction
```

This line error appears almost every minute for the duration of my auction. If my site showed error 522 due to server overload, does that error mean the cause of the crash was when this specific page was viewed by users?

I whitelisted Cloudflare's IPs on WHM. How can I pinpoint the cause of the error and prevent it from happening again?

Thank you

Comment: If you are trying to run some auction side (you mention that) and the site suddenly starts to be overloaded when one auction comes to the end, then you can be 99% certain that someone tries by purpose to prevent your server from being available, so to accept additional offers. Probably someone made a DOS. Not much you can do against that, except maybe blacklisting such IPs on package filter level by an automatic rule. Won't work for a DDOS, though.

Comment: Wouldn't Cloudflare protect me against such threats though?

Comment: Ask them, I would suggest.

Comment: How can I find the IPs potentially involved in the DDOS attack?

Comment: You don't want to know the addresses of DDOS attacks, since that won't help you. A DDOS attack means requests from countless sources at the same time. The first `D` stands for "distributed".

Comment: Voting to close. Diagnosing, never mind fixing performance / capacity problems is really difficult and you haven't even scratched the surface of understanding what is happening here (DDOS is very unlikely)

Comment: Also see [Error 520: Web server is returning an unknown error](https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200171936-Error-520-Web-server-is-returning-an-unknown-error).

Answer (score 0):

As suggested, maybe it's DDoS in which case you could try changing your CloudFlare security settings to high or I'm under attack.

It seems to me though that it would be good to gather more information first, because maybe this isn't the cause. For example maybe you need to up the size of your server, or maybe you need to fine-tune your php or mysql settings, or up the php [max_execution_time](http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

One place to start gathering more info would be by installing [htop](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/ubuntu/using-htop-to-monitor-system-processes-on-linux/) and then watch what happens to your memory and cpu, and which tasks are using your server resources.

Htop won't necessarily solve your problem but it will hopefully point you in the right direction.

Good luck!